# Adding command button to Windows Logon screen

Tags: windows, authentication

I want to implement a self reset password functionality for Windows users. When the Logon screen prompts the domain users should be presented with a forgot password button which will take the user to a password reset wizard. So the problem is how to add a command button to the standard windows logon screen.

Comment: And how do you envisage this password reset functionality working if they can't log in?

Answer (score 7):

Modifying login screens is a rather obscure science.

For Windows XP and below, you will need to create a custom [GINA (Graphical Identification and Authentication) DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378750%28VS.85%29.aspx). This process is described in [this MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163803.aspx).

As for Vista and above, you will need to create a custom Credential Provider. It is demonstrated in [this MSDN magazine article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx).

**I wouldn't recommend doing what you are doing. This could be a huge security breach.**

Answer (score 1):

For implementation of login/authentification in Windows you may read about [GINA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_Identification_and_Authentication),

> GINA is a replaceable dynamically
>   linked library that is loaded early in
>   the boot process in the context of
>   Winlogon when the machine is started

Comment: GINA was replaced with Vista, IIRC

Answer (score 1):

That would depend hugely on the OS; pre-vista, GINA; post-vista, LogonUI can be extended by a custom credential provider (as [discussed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163489.aspx)). However, it won't be easy - and probably risky too.