# Running Self Service C# Winform at Windows Login Screen

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, authentication, credential-providers

I have written a Self Service Password Reset Tool for our internal company users as a C# Winform.

This app consumes other custom Asp.net web services using HTTPS and client certificate based authentication to either generate a random 6 digit code and send to a mobile device or retrieve 3 security questions that have been set by the user when they have enrolled for Self Service.

The Code/Answers are sent back to the web service, if verified, the users AD account is unlocked and their password reset server side.

I think this is all pretty common in any SSPR Tool and is all working fine if accessed from another users machine, however...

Because of the nature of the problem being that the user cant access their machine at the time they need to reset their password, I have been asked if this app can be launched from the Windows login screen.

I have written a POC custom credential provider which adds a new "tile" to the windows 7 login screen and launches my app when its clicked but I cant help but think this may be a really bad idea.

Because of where its being launched from, the app runs in the context of the local SYSTEM user which is already making me nervous!

Looking at other "paid for" SSPR Tools that are out there most seem, at face value to be doing something similar i.e. running an external app at the login screen?

- Is running any app as SYSTEM at the winlogin screen a complete no-no?
- If not, are they any recommendations I should be following to plug any vulnerabilities?
- Is there anything else I could do to reduce the risk (some sort of impersonation/de-elevation when my program is first run?)

Comment: The main logon UI runs as SYSTEM, so it certainly isn't an utterly ridiculous thing to do.  In fact, I suspect that you *have* to be running as SYSTEM in order to present a UI on the secure logon screen.  (I'm not certain.)  At any rate, it might not be a bad idea to do the networking stuff - which is the most vulnerable to attack - in a subprocess running with minimal privileges.

Comment: The answer in this question says that this is a really bad idea but doesnt go into specifics:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13292060/adding-a-button-to-the-windows-7-logon-screen

I'm tempted to go down the route suggested there also, setup a generic domain user and replace the shell for that user with my app.

I should be able to amend the credential provider to automatically log on with the generic user when the tile is clicked which should launch my app but in the context of the standard domain user and not as SYSTEM.

Comment: use group policies to hide the original tile, the CP samples will create a new tile for each provider. You will need the guid's of the original microsoft tiles

Answer (score 1):

On windows credential provider you can either get it to log in and then launch your self service app.   We tried this and the process itself takes too long.

instead we did the following

created a Web app that allows you to register for self service. either questions answers or register an alternate email address.   this is all trivial stuff.

the fun bit was we created a Winform app with a browser component for that url only.    we then created a credential provider that has a link which when clicked would open up the winform app.     we ensured that no right clicking or the ability to launch new windows by configuring the Winform as such.

now if a user has forgotten their password they just click on the link at pre logon.   Winform loads and they do their business.  and then close the Winform.    it's all done at log on screen.

note.    if u try to implement using wpf instead of Winforms the application takes quite some time to load.

happy to share code.   just tell me what u need.      also make sure when creating credential providers that you give them unique ids and not just use Microsoft samples.   you also need to disable the original credential provider otherwise you end up with duplicates.  we used Group policies to disable accordingly.

Comment: Hi,

I know your comment was a good while ago but I have only just come across it.

Comment: We are just in the process of deploying my app and credential provider to all of our machines but the way I had created it, it shows as a separate "Tile" that isn't always displayed unless the user clicks "Switch User".

I would be interested in taking a look at your CP that has incorporated the default login screen and launches your app from there if possible?